# Given two lists of numbers, some zeroes among them, to calculate ratios of corresponding elements and standard deviations of these ratios

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists of numbers, some zeroes among the elements, and would like to calculate the ratios of corresponding elements and the standard deviations of these ratios while setting to zero both the ratios and the standard deviations of those with zero in the denominator positions.

Comment: You need to give an example;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not following `while setting to zero both the ratios and the standard deviations` part. i.e. the part about setting the standard deviation to zero.

May be this is what you want?

```
lst1 = {1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 29};
lst2 = {5, 6, 7, 0, 8, 0};
ratios = MapThread[If[#2 == 0, 0, #1/#2] &, {lst1, lst2}] // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
StandardDeviation[ratios] // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 29};

b = {5, 6, 7, 0, 8, 0};
```

`ReplaceAll` dividing zeros with `Infinity`

```
r = a / (b /. 0 :> Infinity) // N
```

{0.2, 0.333333, 0., 0., 0.5, 0.}

```
StandardDeviation[r]
```

0.211257

Answer (score 1):

```
lst1 = {1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 29};
lst2 = {5, 6, 7, 0, 8, 0};

ratios = Transpose[{lst1, lst2}] /. {a_, 0} :> {0, a} // 
  Map[Apply[Divide]]
```

> {1/5, 1/3, 0, 0, 1/2, 0}

```
StandardDeviation@ratios
```

$\frac{\sqrt{\frac{241}{6}}}{30}$

Answer (score 1):

```
lst1 = {1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 29};
lst2 = {5, 6, 7, 0, 8, 0};
```

---

```
ratios = Cases[Thread[{lst1, lst2}], {a_, b_} :> If[b == 0, 0, a/b]]

(*{1/5, 1/3, 0, 0, 1/2, 0}*)

StandardDeviation@ratios

(*Sqrt[241/6]/30*)
```

Or using `Sort`:

```
ratios = #1/#2 & @@@ (Sort /@ Thread[{lst1, lst2}])

(*{1/5, 1/3, 0, 0, 1/2, 0}*)

StandardDeviation@ratios

(*Sqrt[241/6]/30*)
```